Google Calendar Events API not sending Email Notification when an event is created by API
Email notification is working in this calendar when you are creating event by your own. Notification 'New events An event is added to this calendar' in Calendar is set to 'Email'
Example
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events
{ "summary": "First month review", "start": { "dateTime": "2024-05-30T17:10:00+03:00" }, "end": { "dateTime": "2024-05-30T17:30:00+03:00" }, "reminders": { "useDefault": false, "overrides": [ { "method": "email", "minutes": 5 }, { "method": "popup", "minutes": 2 } ] }, "description": "Discuss the progress so far and the next steps.", "guestsCanInviteOthers": true, "guestsCanModify": true, "sendUpdates": "all", "attendees": [ { "email": "{email}", "role": "editor" }, { "email": "{email}" } ] } 
Event is created, but i got zero notifications.
Scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://mail.google.com https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds
I expect to receive a "new Google event" notification on email to all event participants as soon as it is created.
I have tried to send 'reminders' in request, but it didnt help. nothing changed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
